using the same numeric reference for different objects in the spec
In paragraph one of the spec "a first user" is introduced with characteristic A.
In paragraph five of the spec "a first user" is introduced again with characteristic B.
In paragraph six of the spec "the first user" is referenced.
Questions:

Would it be clear that "the first user" in paragraph six is referencing back to paragraph five?

Is this acceptable?

Or should each time a different user is introduced, it should be
assigned a new, incremental, numeric name?


